# Django: Formset doesn't save as entry already exists

Tags: python, django

I have a formset that faces one of these situations. 1) No database entry exists. New entry for each 'form' is made. 2) Database entry exists, but will be updated.

1) Works with my code, I attached here.
2) Doesn't work. I always receive the error 'already exists'. (It's okay that it already exists, but in that case it should just update the entry, instead of showing me an error)

Anyone who can help me?

```
forms.py

class SocialTixForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = SocialTix
            fields = (
                'coin_mode',
            )

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for visible_field in self.visible_fields():
                visible_field.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

class SocialTixCoinAllocationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Coins
        fields = (
            'ticket',
            'coins',
        )
```

views.py

```
class AdminIncluencerPreferences(AdminPermissionRequiredMixin, AdminBaseAmbassadorView, TemplateView):
    """
    This view will show the ambassador preferences
    """
    template_name = 'influencer/admin/preferences.html'
    success_message = _("Settings have been successfully created.")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['social_form'] = self.social_form
        context['social_coin_allocation_formset'] = self.social_coin_allocation_formset
        return context

    @cached_property
    def social_form(self):
        return SocialTicketingForm(
            instance=self.request.event.event_extension,
            data=self.request.POST or None,
        )

    @cached_property
    def social_coin_allocation_formset(self):
        CoinAllocationFormset = formset_factory(
            SocialTicketingCoinAllocationForm,
            extra=0
        )
        return CoinAllocationFormset(
            data=self.request.POST or None,
            initial=self.request.event.tickets.tickets_as_list(),
        )

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if (self.social_form.is_valid() and
                self.social_coin_allocation_formset.is_valid()):

            self.social_form.save()
            self.social_coin_allocation_formset.save()
```

models.py

```
    class Coins(TimeStampedModel):
                ticket = models.OneToOneField(
                    Ticket,
                    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                    related_name='coins',
                )
                coins = models.PositiveIntegerField(
                    verbose_name='Coins',
                )

    class TicketManager(models.Manager):
            """
            Used for AdminAmbassadorPreferences to allocate coins for tickets
            """
            def tickets_as_list(self):
                tickets = self.get_queryset()
                ticket_list = [{'ticket': ticket} for ticket in tickets]
                return ticket_list


    class Ticket(TimeStampedModel):

            event = models.ForeignKey(
                Event,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                related_name='tickets',
            )  # CASCADE = delete the ticket if the event is deleted
            tax = models.ForeignKey(
                'Tax',
                on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                related_name='tickets',
                blank=True,
                null=True,
            )  # PROTECT = don't allow to delete the ticket tax if a ticket exists
            name = models.CharField(
                max_length=100,
                verbose_name=_("Ticket Name"),
            )
            objects = TicketManager()
```

Comment: Can you also post your model?

Comment: Sure, it's done.